# opencv with cvfilter2d. I'm getting black image

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm trying to aplicate an image filter with cvfilter2d

```
    cvmSet(kernel,0,0,5);
    cvmSet(kernel,0,1,5);
    cvmSet(kernel,0,2,5);   
    cvmSet(kernel,1,0,-3);
    cvmSet(kernel,1,1,0);
    cvmSet(kernel,1,2,-3);
    cvmSet(kernel,2,0,-3);
    cvmSet(kernel,2,1,-3);
    cvmSet(kernel,2,2,-3);
```

and then I aplicate this

```
cvFilter2D(imgMedia,imgRestitucion , kernel, cvPoint(-1,-1) );
```

but my result is a black image...what can I do? there's some alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having basically the same problem--filter2D is also giving me a black image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327086/in-opencv-what-data-types-does-cv2-filter2d-expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution about this.

All you have to do is initialize the kernel with a cvRealScalar number.

```
for(int y=0;y<9;y++) {
    for(int x=0; x<9; x++) {
        cvSet2D(kernel,x,y,cvRealScalar(-0.00132704 ));
    }
}
```

Then you can applicate the image filter to the ker and when you use cvFilter2D you won't get black image.