# In OpenCV, what data types does cv2.filter2D() expect?

Tags: python, opencv, gradient, edge-detection, convolution

I'm teaching myself about edge detectors, and I'm trying to use OpenCV's `filter2D` to implement my own gradient calculator, similar to `cv2.Sobel()`. In the Python interface to OpenCV, `cv2.filter2D()` allows users to convolve an image with a custom filter. In OpenCV nomenclature, this filter is called a "kernel."

Using an image ([per00001.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35993/OpenCV_StackOverflow/per00001.png)) from the [MIT pedestrian dataset](http://cbcl.mit.edu/software-datasets/PedestrianData.html), I find that `cv2.Sobel()` produces a reasonable looking output. (Code is below, [output image is here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35993/OpenCV_StackOverflow/gradientX.png).)

```
#OpenCV's Sobel code (outputs nice-looking gradient)
import cv2, numpy
img = cv2.imread("./per00001.png")

gradientX = cv2.Sobel(img, -1, 1, 0)

compression_params = [cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9]
cv2.imwrite("gradientX.png", gradientX, compression_params)
```

**↑ GOOD**

---

**↓ BROKEN**

When I try to implement my own `Sobel()`-like code (below), I get an [all-black image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35993/OpenCV_StackOverflow/gradientX_customSobel.png). I'm speculating that the problem is with the data type of the kernel parameter (`horizontalSobelMtx`) that I'm passing into `cv2.filter2D()`. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation about the kernel data type for `cv2.filter2D()`.

```
#Custom Sobel code (outputs all-black image)
import cv2, numpy
img = cv2.imread("./per00001.png")

horizontalSobelMtx = [[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]
horizontalSobelMtx = numpy.asanyarray(horizontalSobelMtx) #guessing about appropriate datatype.
gradientX_customSobel = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, horizontalSobelMtx)

compression_params = [cv2.cv.CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9]
cv2.imwrite("gradientX_customSobel.png", gradientX_customSobel, compression_params)
```

So, here are my questions:

1) What data type does `cv2.filter2D(..., kernel, ...)` expect for the `kernel` parameter?

2) If the data type of `kernel` isn't the problem here, then what's causing my custom Sobel code to output a blank image?

Comment: I run your code, and get the right result.

Comment: Did you run the code snippet that has the comment `#Custom Sobel code (outputs all-black image)`?

Comment: I'm also getting the correct results.

Comment: @Froyo is that for the `#OpenCV's Sobel code (outputs nice-looking gradient)` code snippet or the `#Custom Sobel code (outputs all-black image)` code?

Comment: Both the gradientX.png and gradientX_customSobel.png are right.

Comment: I tried your custom edge detector code and it's working fine. Output is great. Here's the image. http://i.imgur.com/S04f5.png

Comment: @Froyo HYRY that's so strange! I just tried using the image from the Sobel tutorial (docs.opencv.org/_images/Sobel_Derivatives_Tutorial_Theory_0.jpg), which I think is the same image that Froyo tried. I'm getting a black image output for the Custom Sobel code.

Comment: You might be getting some errors while saving. Try imshow()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coefficients of the convolution kernel should always be floating-
point numbers. This means that you should use CV_32FC1 when allocating that matrix.
In this particular example, try:

```
horizontalSobelMtx = [[-1,0,1],[-2,0,2],[-1,0,1]]
horizontalSobelMtx = numpy.asanyarray(horizontalSobelMtx, np.float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I believe I have a partial answer.  Basically, you need to weight your kernel.  The way the filter algorithm works is it takes your filter, multiplies it, then adds all the values together and uses them as the new value.  The key is the ADDING part.  Adding 8 different values (some negative, some positive) will usually result in a large number, and displayed, appears black (or in my case, all white).
So you have to compensate for the addition.  Divide all the values in your kernel by the size/area of the kernel.  See the example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html) and note the line

```
  kernel = Mat::ones( kernel_size, kernel_size, CV_32F )/ (float)(kernel_size*kernel_size);
```

They divide everything by kernel_size squared.

Myself, I did this, and it helped (something showed) but it was washed out, so I found my perfect weight by adding this to my code:

```
 int d2weight = 1;
 //... start loop, make your Mat kernel
 kernel = kernel / d2weight;  //put right before your filter2d() call
 createTrackbar("kernel", "kernel", &d2weight, 255, NULL);
```

and fiddled with the bar and right around d2weight = 140 my picture 'popped' into view.